# The feature 'EVENT NOTIFICATION' is not supported with memory optimized tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been battling to create a table type in SQL Server 2016. There are other table types which already exists in the database, but I can't seem to create a new one anymore and I keep getting the error **The feature 'EVENT NOTIFICATION' is not supported with memory optimized tables.** I tried some googling and can't seem to find similar issue. I generated the DB scripts to test locally if on the newly created DB it will work and works just fine. What could I be missing?

My script looks something like this:

```
USE MyDB
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE(
    [Col1] int,
    [Col2] nvarchar(100),
     PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [Col1]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 128)
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )
GO
```

Comment: From the docs: *"Memory-optimized tables and natively compiled stored procedures cannot be created or dropped if there is a server or database event notification for that DDL operation. Remove the server and database event notifications on CREATE TABLE or DROP TABLE and CREATE PROCEDURE or DROP PROCEDURE."* Presumably you have such a event defined on `CREATE TYPE`.

Comment: If you have running trace or any kind DDL Trigger you should stop them first.

Comment: "Presumably you have such a event defined on CREATE TYPE" - or any of its parent events (DDL_TYPE_EVENTS, DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS, DDL_EVENTS) according to sys.event_notification_event_types. Either way, OP should check sys.event_notifications to see what event notifications exist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. It turns out that it was the server level events.
I couldn't find them on the database I was looking at, until I created a fresh DB and added the in memory file group, when I tried to create the table type, it threw the same error. It was at this point I realized that it's at the server level and not the database.
To find these culprits I used: `select * from sys.all_objects where type_desc = 'EVENT_NOTIFICATION'` I then got a copy of these event notifications then dropped them, created the table type, recreated the Event Notifications and all is good now.